# Debian 8 KVM Guest - Loading initial ramdisk

Tags: debian, boot, kvm, ramdisk

I have updated my [KVM management script](https://github.com/programster/KVM-Command-Generator) for Ubuntu 14.04 KVM hosts to support debian 8 guests. After a manual installation (preseed script does not work yet), I am stuck with the the following message on bootup:

[image]

During the installation, I:

- Selected only ssh server and base system utilities.
- Set the grub bootloader to install to the only listed option.
- Used the guided partitioning mode for everything on one partition.
- Used the local UK mirror.

Is there some step I need to be careful to make or can Debian 8 not yet be installed as a KVM guest?

---

### Update

After giving up and deciding to just upgrade a debian 7 VM to debian 8 by updating all of the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `jessie` instead of `wheezy`, I found that I eventually got the same behaviour.

However this instance had a static IP and I found that I could still SSH into the server on that IP, so it looks like **this is some sort of graphics issue** where the server does manage to boot up, we just can't see the login text. How can I resolve this?

---

### Update

This time, on the debian installation created by upgrading debian 7, I can click advanced from the grub menu and select the option with (sysvinit) which works for now. I am hoping this can lead to an explanation of what is going wrong with the normal version that gets booted?

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem, this helped me: http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_8&p=kvm&f=2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to the [link](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_8&p=kvm&f=2) @Someone posted in the comments to the question, I was able to pull this content which fixed the issue for me:

1. on the boot screen (below) press the "e" key to edit the configuration.
   [image]
2. You will be shown a screen like follows.
   [image]
3. Scroll down using the keyboard down arrow. You want the line that says `linux`
   [image]
4. Add the text `console=ttyS0` after the word `quiet` and then press `cntrl + x` to proceed
   [image]
5. Now as root, or using sudo, run the command `systemctl enable getty@ttyS0` in order to never have to go through all those steps again.

Comment: If this happens to you on a virtual terminal on a KVM guest with no ssh access (yet), Escape it to your host shell, then you have to be quick on the keys. Type `virsh console YOURVM` which should fail but then you type `virsh reboot YOURVM` then immediately *up*, *up*, *enter* to replay the console command then keep tapping *up* until you see the grub menu and you've prevented the default from loading.

Comment: @Walf rather than be quick on your keys, you can just use && to queue the commands like: 
`sudo virsh reboot my-vm-id` && `sudo virsh console my-vm-id`

Comment: I assumed that the `start` would be asynchronous and that the console may not exist immediately. Oops.

Comment: To persist the `console=ttyS0` setting, you can edit file _/etc/default/grub_, line *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX*. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem! The result showed that the virtual machine might be out of cpu or memory resource and I solved it by adding arguments **"-smp 4 -m 2048"**

Initially, I was running qemu with command

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -enable-kvm -nographic
```

But the new kernel was stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk"

Later, I tried with

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -enable-kvm -nographic -m 512 -smp 4
```

then, there is a kernel panic, saying "Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory and no killable processes..."

Finally, it's the **solution**

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -enable-kvm -nographic -m 2048 -smp 4
```

Comment: I just tried this and it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the selected answer solved my problem too on Debian8 on a newly created VM. Adding `console=ttyS0` got me the console.

But an important additional information: Like the post author I also created the VM with only base-system and ssh-server. Like many in this situation I was not really interested in having a console but mainly SSH.

So it's important to know that even if the VM might seem stuck, it is running correctly and you can `ssh` into it. You could also start the VM without the `--console` option.

If you used the default network setting (NAT and DHCP) you can get the IP assigned to your VM issuing:

```
# virsh net-dhcp-leases default
```

Or as user:

```
$ virsh --connect qemu:///system net-dhcp-leases default
```

(use the network name your VM are on if it is something else than default)

Knowing the IP you can `ssh` into your VM.