# Accessing Console Of Ubuntu 16.04 KVM Guest

Tags: console, tty, kvm

When I added Debian 8 to my [KVM management tool](https://github.com/programster/KVM-Command-Generator), I found that I [could not access the console unless I added `console=ttyS0` to the grub boot configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203768/debian-8-kvm-guest-loading-initial-ramdisk). It wasn't great but it worked. I am in the process of adding Ubuntu 16.04 to the management tool, and this time when the guest is installed it has the same problem, but I can no longer see the grub menu options when I reboot the instance whilst connected to the console. Therefore, I cannot implement the workaround.

I managed to find the IP address of the guest instance by running `arp -an` on the hypervisor and connecting to the IPs on the KVM bridge until I found the right one. This allowed me to confirm that the guest was installed and running correctly. I would like to be able to connect to the console using `sudo virsh console [guest ID]` in case something goes wrong with the networking or if openssh suddenly decides to stop working. **What do I need to do to be able to connect to the guest ubuntu 16.04 console from the hypervisor?**

My gut feeling is that I should just need to tweak the configuration settings which are accessed by `sudo virsh edit [guestID]`. At the moment I have:

```
...
<serial type='pty'>
  <target port='0'/>
</serial>
<console type='pty'>
  <target type='serial' port='0'/>
</console>
...
```

#### Extra Info

- Ubuntu 14.04 KVM hypervisor using kernel 4.2.0-36-generic
- Virsh 1.2.2

Comment: if you are allocating an IP to the VM by DHCP, see my `find-vm-ip-by-name.sh` script in http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239170/7696.   Even better would be to allocate a static IP by MAC address to the VM in the dhcpd (or dnsmasq) config, and then add a matching entry to your DNS (or `/etc/hosts` file).

Comment: That's useful, but users will need to ensure that they install the `openssh-server` package during installation, otherwise that and my solution below will not be able to help them.

Comment: To me, it's an absolute given that a VM can, should, and WILL have sshd installed.  Even if it only has a private address on a local bridge...it just never occurred to me that sshd wouldn't be installed.  BTW, if there's no network or sshd, and no serial console, `virt-manager` can give access to the console.  The VM may be configured for VNC access (use `virsh dumpxml` and search for `graphics type='vnc'` to check).

Comment: BTW, if you're building ubuntu 16.04 VMs by preseed, add ssh packages to your preseed.cfg (e.g. with `d-i pkgsel/include string ssh`).  Or if users are cloning an existing VM image, make sure it has ssh installed first.

Comment: I've made sure that the default kickstart script that my tool uses will automatically install openssh-server, but I'm thinking about the users who decide to manually step through the installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update 13th March 2017

For those already in the situation described above, you can fix your *existing* guest using the original answer below. However, for those of you who would rather never have to go through this pain again, you can just add the following so the %post section of your kickstart file:

```
%post --nochroot
(
    sed -i "s;quiet;quiet console=ttyS0;" /target/etc/default/grub
    sed -i "s;quiet;quiet console=ttyS0;g" /target/boot/grub/grub.cfg
) 1> /target/root/post_install.log 2>&1
%end
```

This will ensure that the necessary changes to grub are made as described below, so that new guests you deploy through using the kickstart file won't suffer from this problem.

### Original Answer

For those who manage to connect via SSH after finding out the IP using `arp -an` on the host, you can perform the following steps ([taken from the bottom of this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)) **once you are connected to the guest**.

Edit the grub configuration file:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Add the text `console=ttyS0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameter as shown below:

[image]

Then have the grub menu be rebuilt using your change by executing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you should be able to connect to a working console with `virsh console [guest ID]`.

This will keep working as future kernels are added to the system, but **I would much rather have a solution that didn't require me to have SSH access to the guest in the first place**.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @Programster solution works for me. 
Since I do not even have SSH access, I have to install and use virt-edit.

```
sudo apt install libguestfs-tools
sudo virt-edit -d myVM /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Replace all instances of `quiet` with `quiet console=ttyS0` in the grub.cfg file and start my VM for console connect.

```
virsh start myVM && virsh console myVM
```

Do not forget to edit and update grub per @programster answer after login.

Comment: This just saved me a world of pain after upgrading to 18.04. It's just a shame that installing libguestfs-tools requires pulling down a lot of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the grub configuration in a post installation step as suggested in @Programster's excellent answer.  Here is how to do it in some other situations.

When installing Ubuntu 16.04 using a Debconf preseed file, add this to your preseed file:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string ( \
    sed -i "s;quiet;quiet console=ttyS0;" /target/etc/default/grub;    \
    sed -i "s;quiet;quiet console=ttyS0;g" /target/boot/grub/grub.cfg \
) 1> /target/root/post_install.log 2>&1
```

When installing RHEL 7 or CentOS 7 using Kickstart, add this to your kickstart file:

```
%post --nochroot --log /mnt/sysimage/root/post.log
(
    sed -i "s;quiet;quiet console=ttyS0;"  /mnt/sysimage/etc/default/grub
    sed -i "s;quiet;quiet console=ttyS0;g" /mnt/sysimage/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
) > /mnt/sysimage/root/post_install.log 2>&1
%end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and easier method as per the [redhat docs](https://leonjza.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/kvm-redirecting-centos-kernel-and-tty-output-to-a-virtual-serial-console/)

```
grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="console=ttyS0"
reboot
```